# Getting ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:
I have three conditions profit, loss and discount

```
if  df['Condition'] == "Profit":
        df["price"]= df["costprice"]- 1.5*df["sp"]
elif df['Condition'] == "Loss":
        df["price"]= df["costprice"]- 1.5*df["sp"]             
else:
      df["price"]= df["targetprice"]-1.5*df["sp"]
```

Comment: Use `np.select`

Comment: Please show at least piece of your `df`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `apply` call instead:

```
def func(x):
    if  x[1] == "Profit":
            x[2]= x[3]- 1.5*x[4]
    elif x[1] == "Loss":
            x[2]= x[3]- 1.5*x[4]             
    else:
          x[2]= x[5]-1.5*x[4]
df = df.apply(func)
print(df)
```

Comment: Getting key error condition

Comment: @Thedatageek Please comment to me your columns in order

Comment: commodity, condition, price, costprice, sp , targetprice, sellerinfo, discount etc.

Comment: getting TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float',  in  x[2]= x[5]-1.5*x[4]

Comment: sp is float 64 !

Comment: should it be map instead of *. ??